# Proguard: use variable to point to the sdk directory

Tags: android, proguard

I have these two lines in some of my proguard.cfg files:

```
-libraryjars /path/to/sdk/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10/libs/maps.jar
-libraryjars /path/to/sdk/android-sdk-linux/tools/support/annotations.jar
```

**My question is whether there is some variable one can use to avoid having a hardcoded path to the sdk?**

Otherwise when I commit the file into svn, the other developers must change the file manually, which is not really maintainable.

I've found the `<java.home>` variable, but `<android.sdk>` or `<sdk.dir>` don't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
-libraryjars <android.sdk>/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-10/libs/maps.jar
-libraryjars <android.sdk>/tools/support/annotations.jar
```

if you make sure that android.sdk is defined as a Java system property. This may mean that you have to pass it to the JVM, e.g. with something like

```
java -Dandroid.sdk=$ANDROID_HOME ......
```