# How to pass environment variables to proguard maven plugin?

Tags: java, maven, proguard

I'm configuring my project's pom to include [proguard plugin](https://github.com/wvengen/proguard-maven-plugin). I need to pass some environment variables down to the proguard configuration file. [I know that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17040212) if I pass to proguard's jvm a Java System Property I can evaluate it. So the question is, how can I pass a Java System Property to the proguard maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Simple provide the system-variable to the java which run maven 
The best way to do it is using ".mvn" folder with "jvm.config" file.

```
.mvn
  jvm.config
pom.xml
```

In jvm.config you can set any system varaible, which will be visible for maven, e.g.:

```
-Xmx1024m -Duser.language=en
```

P.S.
You need at leat maven version 3.3.1 for this feature:
https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html (JVM and Command Line Options)

Comment: I'm using maven 3.3.9 and it looks like this is not working with my configuration and using proguard-maven-plugin (I've added it in the main post) :(